# Square API searching customers by name

Tags: python, square

Square's Customer API only lets you search for customers by email or phone number. Ideally I want to fuzzy search by first and last name. Is there a way to natively do this through Squares API or will I have to list all customers (Would be around 20,000 - 30,000) and implement a searching algorithm in Python?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Currently there isn't a way to search by first and last name but you can use our new [GraphQL](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/devtools/graphql)to get customer name and ID to do a native search faster then parsing the results from the APIs.